# Suddenly SMS are not being sent using AWS SNS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, aws-sdk-nodejs

My current implementation was working in January 2022, but since the last 15 days, SMS are not being sent though I get log of success.

Here is my code,

```
try {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const params = {
            Message: message,
            MessageStructure: 'string',
            PhoneNumber: to,
          };
        
          const paramsAtt = {
            attributes: { /* required */
              DefaultSMSType: 'Transactional',
            },
          };

          sns.setSMSAttributes(paramsAtt, (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
              logger.error(err, err.stack);
            } else {
              logger.debug(data);
              sns.publish(params, (snsErr, snsData) => {
                if (snsErr) {
                  // an error occurred
                  logger.error("Err while sending SMS ==> "+JSON.stringify(snsErr));
                  reject (false);
                } else {
                  // successful response
                  logger.info("SMS send successfully : "+ JSON.stringify(snsData));
                  resolve (true)
                }
              });
            }
          });
    })
} catch (err) {
    throw err;
}
```

I checked the statistics under the SNS service. It depicts that every message is failing though I got the success logs.

Below is the dashboard attachment:

[image]

Below is the log attachment:

[image]

Thank you in advance

Comment: Could it be this? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/channels-sms-us-requirements.html That change was supposed to take effect last June, but I think there was a delay in the change rolling out. Also there is a budget limit that must be configured for SMS sending in AWS, you should check if you have hit your account's current limit.

Comment: Thank you @MarkB for your suggestion. But the actual issue is that quota is expired.

Comment: I think you mean "exceeded", and yes that was my second suggestion.